# Vercel: This Serverless Function (FUNCTION_INVOCATION_FAILED)

Tags: vercel, sveltekit, fastify

I have an error that appears when I try to access my link

- This Serverless Function has crashed.
- Your connection is working correctly.
- Vercel is working correctly.

500: INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
Code: FUNCTION_INVOCATION_FAILED
ID: cdg1:cdg1::bgdnz-1676557396498-149041f4043b

```
[GET] /6OzxT
15:07:51:26
2023-02-16T14:07:51.324Z    020abb04-a238-441a-8a1d-5a4fb96d66c3    ERROR   Unhandled Promise Rejection     {"errorType":"Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection","errorMessage":"TypeError: fetch failed","reason":{"errorType":"TypeError","errorMessage":"fetch failed","cause":{"errorType":"ConnectTimeoutError","errorMessage":"Connect Timeout Error","code":"UND_ERR_CONNECT_TIMEOUT","name":"ConnectTimeoutError","message":"Connect Timeout Error","stack":["ConnectTimeoutError: Connect Timeout Error","    at onConnectTimeout (/var/task/vercel/path0/node_modules/undici/lib/core/connect.js:182:24)","    at /var/task/vercel/path0/node_modules/undici/lib/core/connect.js:129:46","    at Immediate._onImmediate (/var/task/vercel/path0/node_modules/undici/lib/core/connect.js:170:9)","    at process.processImmediate (node:internal/timers:471:21)"]},"stack":["TypeError: fetch failed","    at fetch (/var/task/vercel/path0/node_modules/undici/index.js:113:13)","    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)"]},"promise":{},"stack":["Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection: TypeError: fetch failed","    at process.<anonymous> (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1194:17)","    at process.emit (node:events:525:35)","    at emit (node:internal/process/promises:149:20)","    at processPromiseRejections (node:internal/process/promises:283:27)","    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:32)"]}
Unknown application error occurred
Runtime.Unknown
```

I tried to add a try/catch, and normally it should be redirected to the URL (here steellgold.fr)

+page.server.ts (Redirect page) (https://preview.linkfy.fr/6OzxT)

```
import { PUBLIC_URL, PUBLIC_API_URL } from "$env/static/public";
import type { Link } from "$lib/types/link.type";
import { restRequest } from "$lib/utils/request/request";
import { error, redirect } from "@sveltejs/kit";
import type { PageServerLoad } from "./$types";

// eslint-disable-next-line
export const load = (async({ params }) => {
  if (!params.slug) throw redirect(303, PUBLIC_URL);

  const data = await restRequest<Link>("get", PUBLIC_URL + "api/link", {
    query: {
      slug: params.slug
    }
  }, [], true);

  if (!data.success) {
    throw error(404, { message: "This link not exist or has been disabled", code: 404 });
  }

  try {
    fetch(PUBLIC_API_URL + "link/" + params.slug);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }

  if (!data.data.status) throw error(423, { message: "This link has been disabled", code: 423 });
  throw redirect(303, data.data.url);
}) satisfies PageServerLoad;
```

increment.ts (Fastify route fort increment links)

````
import { FastifyReply, FastifyRequest } from "fastify";
import { app } from "../..";
import { Link } from "../../types/link";
import { error, success, warn } from "../../utils/logger";
import prisma from "../../utils/prisma";

app.get("/link/:slug", {
  handler: async(request: FastifyRequest<{ Params: Link }>, reply: FastifyReply) => {
    reply.status(200).send({ message: "Correctly routed received request." });

    warn(`[GET] incrementing link with slug /${request.params.slug}.`);

    const link = await prisma.link.findUnique({
      where: { slug: request.params.slug }
    });

    if (!link) {
      reply.status(404).send({ error: "Link not found" });
      error(`[404] Link with slug /${request.params.slug} not found.`);
      return;
    }

    await prisma.link.update({
      where: { slug: request.params.slug },
      data: { clicks: link.clicks + 1 }
    });

    success(`[200] Link with slug /${request.params.slug} incremented by 1.`);
    return reply.status(200).send({
      message: "Link incremented successfully."
    });
  }
});```


All codes is open-source: https://github.com/Steellgold/Linkfy or https://github.com/Steellgold/LinkfyAPI if you want
````